# Grails 4.0.11 GroovyConsole error with Gorm domain class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, groovy-console

The following test works in a Grails controller:

Domain class:

```
package freight

class CodeList {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String codeType
    String code
    String description
  
    static constraints = {
        codeType nullable: false, blank: false
        code nullable: false, blank: false, unique: 'codeType'
        description nullable: true, blank: true
    }

    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

Code in controller action:

```
def o = CodeList.get(10254)
println o as JSON
```

Output:

```
{"id":10254,"code":"AFR","codeType":"AOC_CODE","description":"Africa"}
```

When I try this in `grails console` I get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'freight.CodeList : 10254' with class 'freight.CodeList' to class 'freight.CodeList'
    at freight.CodeList.get(CodeList.groovy)
    at freight.CodeList$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at ConsoleScript1.run(ConsoleScript1:3)
```

[image]

What's wrong with this?

The following runs without error and gets the same row:

```
def row = CodeList.findById(10254)
def rows = CodeList.findAllWhere(id: 10254L) // println rows[0]
```

**Alternative solution**

I installed the [Grails web-based Groovy console plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/sheehan/console) and that works much better and faster than `grails console`. Wish I have found this sooner.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/i-get-cannot-cast-object-object-groovy-exception

Comment: @seesharper I read the thread, but don't think it's related to Grails. The following does work in Grails GroovyConsole without error: `def rows = CodeList.findAllWhere(id: 10254L) println rows[0]` which is the same row.  `CodeList.findById(10254)` also works fine

Comment: Could you send a link to your PoC project repo?